# Upgrading to .NET Core 3.1: Replacement for UserManager.NormalizeKey method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm updating an ASP.NET Core project from 2.2 to 3.1. I've sorted out everything else using the migration docs, but it looks like [`UserManager<TUser>.NormalizeKey(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.normalizekey?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_UserManager_1_NormalizeKey_System_String_) has just disappeared after v2.2, and I can't find any migration docs around it.

From [what I can tell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41409692/what-is-the-use-of-normalized-email-username-in-net-core-identityuser-model) it does not seem necessary to use. But I'm not sure and we have it sprinkled around everywhere.

For posterity, the error is: `The name 'NormalizeKey' does not exist in the current context`

My code is something like:

```cs
public virtual async Task<IdentityResult> AddToRequestedRoleAsync(ApplicationUser user, string role)
{
  if (user == null) {
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
  }

  var normalizedRole = NormalizeKey(role);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In later versions of .NET Core, `NormalizeKey` has been replaced by [`NormalizeEmail`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.normalizeemail?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and [`NormalizeName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.normalizename?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

You may not need to normalize, since [`FindByEmailAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.findbyemailasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1) will normalize the parameter for you.

Comment: I see. It looks like this was sprinkled everywhere (lots of user fields) without realization of what it actually does.