# UserManager.FindByNameAsync Returns null for Existing User in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, identity

I am encountering an issue with UserManager.FindByNameAsync in an ASP.NET Core application where it returns null even though the user exists in the database. I am trying to retrieve user roles based on the username, but the method fails to find the user.

```
public async Task<string> GetUserRolesByUserId(string userName)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
    
    if (user == null)
    {
        return "";
    }

    var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
    return string.Join(",", roles);
}
```

**Expected Behavior:**
The method should find the user "TonyMontana" and return their roles.

**Actual Behavior:**
FindByNameAsync returns null for the user "TonyMontana", even though this user exists in the database with the exact same username.

**Additional Information:**

I have confirmed that the user "TonyMontana" exists in the database.
The username in the database matches the case of the username passed to FindByNameAsync.
The UserManager instance is configured in the Startup.cs.
I'm not sure why FindByNameAsync is unable to find the user. Is this a case sensitivity issue, or could there be something wrong with how the UserManager is configured or used in my application?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Update:

Program.cs

```
using System.Text;
using Database;
using Database.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using WebApi.Setup;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>();

var secretKey= builder.Configuration["JwtConfig:JWTSecretKey"];

if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(secretKey)) 
{
    secretKey= "XXX-123-YYY-456";
}

 // Register JWTService with the necessary dependencies
builder.Services.AddScoped<JWTService>(provider => 
    {
        var userManager = provider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<Users>>();
        return new JWTService(secretKey, userManager);
    });

// builder.Services.AddSingleton(new JWTService(secretKey));

builder.Services.AddIdentity<Users, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey)),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew= TimeSpan.Zero
    };
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
// app.UseHttpsRedirection();

 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseAuthorization();

 app.MapControllers();
 app.Run();
```

Comment: "Id" "UserName" "Password" "ContactNo" "ProfilePicPath" "Bio" "Address" "LastActiveTimestamp" "CreatedAt" "UpdatedAt" "NormalizedUserName" "Email" "NormalizedEmail" "EmailConfirmed" "PasswordHash" "SecurityStamp" "ConcurrencyStamp" "PhoneNumber" "PhoneNumberConfirmed" "TwoFactorEnabled" "LockoutEnd" "LockoutEnabled" "AccessFailedCount"
"e4c8f8b3-9b16-4c58-b8b1-4f4c9e8a3f29" "TonyMontana" "123456" "123456"       "TONYMONTANA" "tonymontana@gmail.com"           4

Comment: Hi @SocialCircle , my table looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXp6W.png, your table has more filed, could you build a small demo and share it via gihub ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to make sure `NormalizedUserName` column in AspNetUsers table in database have the value:`TONYMONTANA` . If `NormalizedUserName` column  was NULL which meant it wouldn't find it, then UserManager.FindByNameAsync returns null .

result:

[image]

You can have a look at  [use of NormalizedUsername](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41409692/what-is-the-use-of-normalized-email-username-in-net-core-identityuser-model) to know more.

Comment: hi Qing; I have filled the normalizedusername column with same text but still nothing.

Comment: Hi@SocialCircle ,could you share your `AspNetUsers` table ?